# What kind of house plant is this?

Tags: species-identification, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

[image]
This is a house plant I have that I love but I don’t know what it’s called. I’d love to research it and even buy more but it’s name is a mystery. Picture taken in Ontario, Canada.

Comment: IMO, this question would be a better fit on [gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

It looks to be a Clivia; The English common names are Natal lily or bush lily.

It's a plant that comes originally from Africa but it now commonly sold as house plants.

The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clivia) give a good information about that plant.

Example:

[image: Clivia miniata]

Picture taken from [this site](http://www.africanplants.senckenberg.de/root/index.php?page_id=78&id=4645).

You have also to notice this is a toxic plant and to keep away from small children or pets.

Comment: For downvoter(s), please explain why my answer is not good and how it can be improved? If you think it's wrong, please just tell what the good answer (and post it as well).

Comment: not sure about the down votes, but maybe you could add a good description or image to show the similarities between the Clivia and the plant in question.

Comment: I added some more details as requested. If someone have a better answer I would delete mine without problem.